# PHP Looping through JSON data without knowing the numbers of data

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get all images from an image API. It returns a maximum of 500 result at a time and if the result has a `next_page` field, then I have to grab the value of that field and add it to the URL. The code should continue looping until that field is absent. I used the following code to grab the first two pages:

```php
$key = true;
$link = 'https://url.com/dhj/?prefix=images&type=download';
$json = file_get_contents($link);
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$dataArray = array();
foreach ($data["images"] as $r)
{
    array_push($dataArray, array($r["id"], $r["image"]));
}
while($key)
{
    if($data["next_page"])
    {
        $key=true;
        $link2 = "https://url.com/dhj/?prefix=images&type=download&next_page=" . $data[$next_page];
        $json2 = file_get_contents($link2);
        $data2 = json_decode($json2, true);
        foreach ($data2["images"] as $r2)
        {
            array_push($dataArray, array($r2["id"], $r2["image"]));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $key=false;
    }
}
```

This should fetch 2000 records but is only fetching 1000 records, so it appears the loop is not working as expected.

Comment: It should return 2000 records but only shows 1000 records, so basically the loop is not working. It is just going through two loops instead of 4

Comment: Could you be more specific about the API you're hitting? There's a __lot__ of ways to provide pagination information, so without being able to interact with it it would take a lot of explanation.

Comment: That's because you have only set up 2 fetches; the initial one outside the loop, and a second one inside the loop. If you keep up like this you will need a new loop for each page of results, which I don't think you want!

Comment: So the api will return 500 rows and it will have a field called next_page and we need to include the next_page value in every other page to return value. When the next_page is not present, then the loop will stop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your problem is that you are only fetching twice. The second time, you never check `$data2` for a next page, so everything stops. You do not want to keep going like this, or you will need `$data3`, `$data4`, etc.

A `do`/`while` loop is similar to a `while` loop, except that it always runs at least once. The condition is evaluated at the end of the loop instead of the beginning. You can use that behaviour to ensure you always get the first page of data, and then use the condition to check if you should keep getting more.

```php
$page = "";
do {
    $link = "https://url.com/dhj/?prefix=images&type=download&next_page=$page";
    $json = file_get_contents($link);
    $data = json_decode($json, true);
    foreach ($data["images"] as $r) {
        $dataArray[] = [$r["id"], $r["image"]];
    }
    $page = $data["next_page"] ?? "";
} while ($page);
```

Note I've got rid of your `array_push()` call. This is rarely used in PHP because the `$var[]` syntax is less verbose and doesn't require predeclaration of the array. Likewise, calls to `array()` have long been replaced by use of array literal syntax.
The expression `$page = $data["next_page"] ?? ""` uses the null coalesce operator, and is identical to:

```php
if (isset($data["next_page"])) {
    $page = $data["next_page"];
} else {
    $page = "";
}
```

Comment: Big Saviour. Thank you very much. Just what I was looking :)